# Convert list into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've this list,

```
grid = [['r', 0.01529051987767584, 0.001, -1],
 ['r', 0.9357798165137615, 0.03162277660168379, 39],
 ['r', 0.9480122324159022, 1.0, 79],
 ['r', 0.8899082568807339, 1000.0, 9],
 ['c', 0.9327217125382263, 0.001, 49],
 ['c', 0.9724770642201835, 0.03162277660168379, 89],
 ['c', 0.9724770642201835, 31.622776601683793, 19],
 ['c', 0.9724770642201835, 1000.0, 59]]
```

I need to convert this into a dataframe to get a grid where

```
1st colname = Id 
2nd colname = ratio 
3rd Colname = C
4th colname = Iter
```

Values for each column are comma separated from the list

Thank you in advance if you can help.
Rgds

Comment: I take that `df = pd.DataFrame(grid)` didn't work for you?

Comment: See the examples of how to build a DataFrame [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: Please provide the code for _what you've tried based on your own research_, and describe what went wrong with your attempt

Comment: Hi Henry,, Worked just fine, df = pd.DataFrame(grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dataframe using a list of lists directly by calling `pd.DataFrame(data=a_list)`. You can give column names with the `columns` keyword, provided that the column names are equal to the number of elements in the sublist.

Just use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(grid, columns=["ID", "Ratio", "C", "Iter"])

print(df)
  ID     Ratio            C  Iter
0  r  0.015291     0.001000    -1
1  r  0.935780     0.031623    39
2  r  0.948012     1.000000    79
3  r  0.889908  1000.000000     9
4  c  0.932722     0.001000    49
5  c  0.972477     0.031623    89
6  c  0.972477    31.622777    19
7  c  0.972477  1000.000000    59
```

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho Why do I not deserve the selected answer? :( I answered first!

Comment: Answering first [isn't itself a good reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/284827) to get accepted. As an outsider to Python, both answers look like they could do with some more explanation as to how they work. Not to say that I think either answer should be accepted over the other.

Comment: @Pissal, I'm sorry man, I just check the answer was on the top, I didn't realize yours answer was first. Both are correct. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
colnames = ["id", "ratio", "c", "iter"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=grid, columns=colnames)
```