# Yahoo Finance API yf.Ticker(ticker).info to CSV problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance, yahoo

When I'm using

```
ticker = "MSFT"
stock = yf.Ticker('MSFT').history('5y')

stock
```

I get a dataframe in response

When I use

```
ticker = "MSFT"
stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
stock_info
```

I'm receiving a list from Yahoo finance API. How can I transform this list to a Dataframe in Pandas?
So I could use

```
stock.to_csv(folder + ticker + ".csv") => Working with 'history' data

stock_info.to_csv(folder + ticker + ".csv") => Not working with 'info' data because it's a list not a dataframe.
```

How can I save yf.Ticker(ticker).info data to a csv?

[image]

```
ticker = "MSFT"
stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
stock_info
stock_info.to_csv(folder + ticker + ".csv")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [158], line 4
      2 stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
      3 stock_info
----> 4 stock_info.to_csv(folder + ticker + ".csv")

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'


ticker = "MSFT"
stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
stock_info

{'zip': '98052-6399',
 'sector': 'Technology',
 'fullTimeEmployees': 221000,
 'longBusinessSummary': 'Microsoft Corporation develops, licenses, and supports software, services, devices, and solutions worldwide. The company operates in three segments: Productivity and Business Processes, Intelligent Cloud, and More Personal Computing. The Productivity and Business Processes segment offers Office, Exchange, SharePoint, Microsoft Teams, Office 365 Security and Compliance, Microsoft Viva, and Skype for Business; Skype, Outlook.com, OneDrive, and LinkedIn; and Dynamics 365, a set of cloud-based and on-premises business solutions for organizations and enterprise divisions. The Intelligent Cloud segment licenses SQL, Windows Servers, Visual Studio, System Center, and related Client Access Licenses; GitHub that provides a collaboration platform and code hosting service for developers; Nuance provides healthcare and enterprise AI solutions; and Azure, a cloud platform. It also offers enterprise support, Microsoft consulting, and nuance professional services to assist customers in developing, deploying, and managing Microsoft server and desktop solutions; and training and certification on Microsoft products. The More Personal Computing segment provides Windows original equipment manufacturer (OEM) licensing and other non-volume licensing of the Windows operating system; Windows Commercial, such as volume licensing of the Windows operating system, Windows cloud services, and other Windows commercial offerings; patent licensing; and Windows Internet of Things. It also offers Surface, PC accessories, PCs, tablets, gaming and entertainment consoles, and other devices; Gaming, including Xbox hardware, and Xbox content and services; video games and third-party video game royalties; and Search, including Bing and Microsoft advertising. The company sells its products through OEMs, distributors, and resellers; and directly through digital marketplaces, online stores, and retail stores. Microsoft Corporation was founded in 1975 and is headquartered in Redmond, Washington.',
 'city': 'Redmond',
 'phone': '425 882 8080',
 'state': 'WA',
 'country': 'United States',
 'companyOfficers': [],
 'website': 'https://www.microsoft.com',
 'maxAge': 1,
 'address1': 'One Microsoft Way',
 'fax': '425 706 7329',
 'industry': 'Software—Infrastructure',
 'ebitdaMargins': 0.48672,
 'profitMargins': 0.34366,
 'grossMargins': 0.6826,
 'operatingCashflow': 87693000704,
 'revenueGrowth': 0.106,
 'operatingMargins': 0.41691002,
 'ebitda': 98841001984,
 'targetLowPrice': 255,
 'recommendationKey': 'buy',
 'grossProfits': 135620000000,
 'freeCashflow': 46155874304,
...
 'dayHigh': 236.6,
 'coinMarketCapLink': None,
 'regularMarketPrice': 235.87,
 'preMarketPrice': None,
 'logo_url': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/microsoft.com'}
```

I don't understand how I can change this list into something I can write to CSV

```
{'zip': '98052-6399',
 'sector': 'Technology',
 'fullTimeEmployees': 221000,
 'longBusinessSummary': 'Microsoft Corporation develops, licenses, and supports software, services, devices, and solutions worldwide. The company operates in three segments: Productivity and Business Processes, Intelligent Cloud, and More Personal Computing. The Productivity and Business Processes segment offers Office, Exchange, SharePoint, Microsoft Teams, Office 365 Security and Compliance, Microsoft Viva, and Skype for Business; Skype, Outlook.com, OneDrive, and LinkedIn; and Dynamics 365, a set of cloud-based and on-premises business solutions for organizations and enterprise divisions. The Intelligent Cloud segment licenses SQL, Windows Servers, Visual Studio, System Center, and related Client Access Licenses; GitHub that provides a collaboration platform and code hosting service for developers; Nuance provides healthcare and enterprise AI solutions; and Azure, a cloud platform. It also offers enterprise support, Microsoft consulting, and nuance professional services to assist customers in developing, deploying, and managing Microsoft server and desktop solutions; and training and certification on Microsoft products. The More Personal Computing segment provides Windows original equipment manufacturer (OEM) licensing and other non-volume licensing of the Windows operating system; Windows Commercial, such as volume licensing of the Windows operating system, Windows cloud services, and other Windows commercial offerings; patent licensing; and Windows Internet of Things. It also offers Surface, PC accessories, PCs, tablets, gaming and entertainment consoles, and other devices; Gaming, including Xbox hardware, and Xbox content and services; video games and third-party video game royalties; and Search, including Bing and Microsoft advertising. The company sells its products through OEMs, distributors, and resellers; and directly through digital marketplaces, online stores, and retail stores. Microsoft Corporation was founded in 1975 and is headquartered in Redmond, Washington.',
 'city': 'Redmond',
 'phone': '425 882 8080',
 'state': 'WA',
 'country': 'United States',
 'companyOfficers': [],
 'website': 'https://www.microsoft.com',
 'maxAge': 1,
 'address1': 'One Microsoft Way',
 'fax': '425 706 7329',
 'industry': 'Software—Infrastructure',
 'ebitdaMargins': 0.48672,
 'profitMargins': 0.34366,
 'grossMargins': 0.6826,
 'operatingCashflow': 87693000704,
 'revenueGrowth': 0.106,
 'operatingMargins': 0.41691002,
 'ebitda': 98841001984,
 'targetLowPrice': 255,
 'recommendationKey': 'buy',
 'grossProfits': 135620000000,
 'freeCashflow': 46155874304,
 'targetMedianPrice': 296,
 'currentPrice': 235.87,
 'earningsGrowth': -0.133,
 'currentRatio': 1.84,
 'returnOnAssets': 0.15223,
 'numberOfAnalystOpinions': 45,
 'targetMeanPrice': 307.58,
 'debtToEquity': 44.442,
 'returnOnEquity': 0.42875,
 'targetHighPrice': 411,
 'totalCash': 107244003328,
 'totalDebt': 77136003072,
 'totalRevenue': 203074994176,
 'totalCashPerShare': 14.387,
 'financialCurrency': 'USD',
 'revenuePerShare': 27.142,
 'quickRatio': 1.585,
 'recommendationMean': 1.7,
 'exchange': 'NMS',
 'shortName': 'Microsoft Corporation',
 'longName': 'Microsoft Corporation',
 'exchangeTimezoneName': 'America/New_York',
 'exchangeTimezoneShortName': 'EDT',
 'isEsgPopulated': False,
 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds': '-14400000',
 'quoteType': 'EQUITY',
 'symbol': 'MSFT',
 'messageBoardId': 'finmb_21835',
 'market': 'us_market',
 'annualHoldingsTurnover': None,
 'enterpriseToRevenue': 8.51,
 'beta3Year': None,
 'enterpriseToEbitda': 17.484,
 '52WeekChange': -0.2838753,
 'morningStarRiskRating': None,
 'forwardEps': 11.35,
 'revenueQuarterlyGrowth': None,
 'sharesOutstanding': 7454470144,
 'fundInceptionDate': None,
 'annualReportExpenseRatio': None,
 'totalAssets': None,
 'bookValue': 23.276,
 'sharesShort': 38213792,
 'sharesPercentSharesOut': 0.0050999997,
 'fundFamily': None,
 'lastFiscalYearEnd': 1656547200,
 'heldPercentInstitutions': 0.71777,
 'netIncomeToCommon': 69788999680,
 'trailingEps': 9.29,
 'lastDividendValue': 0.62,
 'SandP52WeekChange': -0.1544562,
 'priceToBook': 10.133615,
 'heldPercentInsiders': 0.00071000005,
 'nextFiscalYearEnd': 1719705600,
 'yield': None,
 'mostRecentQuarter': 1664496000,
 'shortRatio': 1.28,
 'sharesShortPreviousMonthDate': 1663200000,
 'floatShares': 7399682766,
 'beta': 0.960206,
 'enterpriseValue': 1728178552832,
 'priceHint': 2,
 'threeYearAverageReturn': None,
 'lastSplitDate': 1045526400,
 'lastSplitFactor': '2:1',
 'legalType': None,
 'lastDividendDate': 1660694400,
 'morningStarOverallRating': None,
 'earningsQuarterlyGrowth': -0.144,
 'priceToSalesTrailing12Months': 8.658308,
 'dateShortInterest': 1665705600,
 'pegRatio': 1.8,
 'ytdReturn': None,
 'forwardPE': 20.781496,
 'lastCapGain': None,
 'shortPercentOfFloat': 0.0050999997,
 'sharesShortPriorMonth': 42967330,
 'impliedSharesOutstanding': 0,
 'category': None,
 'fiveYearAverageReturn': None,
 'previousClose': 226.75,
 'regularMarketOpen': 226.24,
 'twoHundredDayAverage': 272.84604,
 'trailingAnnualDividendYield': 0.0112017635,
 'payoutRatio': 0.26700002,
 'volume24Hr': None,
 'regularMarketDayHigh': 236.6,
 'navPrice': None,
 'averageDailyVolume10Day': 34581880,
 'regularMarketPreviousClose': 226.75,
 'fiftyDayAverage': 248.0068,
 'trailingAnnualDividendRate': 2.54,
 'open': 226.24,
 'toCurrency': None,
 'averageVolume10days': 34581880,
 'expireDate': None,
 'algorithm': None,
 'dividendRate': 2.72,
 'exDividendDate': 1668556800,
 'circulatingSupply': None,
 'startDate': None,
 'regularMarketDayLow': 226.06,
 'currency': 'USD',
 'trailingPE': 25.389666,
 'regularMarketVolume': 40593443,
 'lastMarket': None,
 'maxSupply': None,
 'openInterest': None,
 'marketCap': 1758285791232,
 'volumeAllCurrencies': None,
 'strikePrice': None,
 'averageVolume': 26490917,
 'dayLow': 226.06,
 'ask': 235.7,
 'askSize': 1200,
 'volume': 40593443,
 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': 349.67,
 'fromCurrency': None,
 'fiveYearAvgDividendYield': 1.2,
 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': 219.13,
 'bid': 235.5,
 'tradeable': False,
 'dividendYield': 0.0115,
 'bidSize': 900,
 'dayHigh': 236.6,
 'coinMarketCapLink': None,
 'regularMarketPrice': 235.87,
 'preMarketPrice': None,
 'logo_url': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/microsoft.com'}
```

This is the full response from Yahoo Finance API from which I only need 'freeCashflow', 'industry', 'debtToEquity, 'returnOnEquity', 'sharesOutstanding' to CSV

```
ticker = "MSFT"
stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
stock_info

df = pd.DataFrame(stock_info)
df
```

This code returns an empty df but I can see the columns. 154 columns but 0 rows??? I should have 1 row of data.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507886/convert-list-into-dataframe)

Comment: What module is `'yf`?  Also, please use text, not screenshots.  It looks like `info` returns a `dict`, not a `list`.  A more natural format to write that would be in `json`, but you could do it using `csv` by defining every `dict` key as a csv column, either directly or converting it to a df as you asked.

Comment: yf is yahoo finance module for yf.Ticker('MSFT').history('5y') i can save to csv using same code. yf.Ticker(ticker).info gives error because it's different format but I don't know what format it is.

Comment: @craigb it's the response I get from Yahoo Finance API when I look up .info But I don't know what format it is. And how to change it to a df. I'm saving all tickers to csv documents. So I would like to save it as MSFT.csv with this .info data in it. Just don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using

```
        stock_info
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stock_info,orient='index').T
```

Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

The response is a dict so wrap it in square brackets and pass it to pandas.

```
pd.DataFrame([stock_info]).to_csv("/path/to/write/MSFT.csv", index=False)
```